# Best way to add image in pdf with itextsharp

Tags: itext

I've a problem but i'm not able to find a solution.
I need to show an image into pdf with itextsharp.. The problem is that, once a format is given (for example A4), i'd like that page size changes from A4 or A4Landscape if useful to show image in the best way..that is basing on image dimension A4 or A4landscape must be shown to get image as maximized as possible (without loosing proportion).
Can you help me? I tried and tried, but I don't find correct solution. Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide your code so far?

Comment: sure...thanks for your reply...I hope it can be clear

Comment: The question isn't clear. Do you want to maintain the page size and change the image size? Or do you want to keep the image size and change the page size? What if the ratio of the image is different from the ratio of an A4 page? Are white margins acceptable?